# C++ Can't subtract two strings

Tags: c++, string, operator-keyword, subtraction

I want to subtract two strings in this code, but it won't let me do it and gives an operator - error. This code basically tries to separate a full input name into two outputs: first and last names. Please Help! Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string employeeName, firstName, lastName;
int pos1, difference;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter your full name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, employeeName);

    pos1 = employeeName.find(" ");
    difference = pos1 - 0;
    lastName = employeeName.erase(0,difference);
    firstName = employeeName - lastName;

    cout << lastName << firstName << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can use std::string.substr method

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I want to do it the simple - method because this q was on my test, and we haven't covered advanced stuff.

Comment: Look in your C++ textbook or reference book, to see all the available operators with `std::string` and verify the subtraction operator.

Comment: Note that `string::erase` modifies the input string, so even if `firstName = employeeName - lastName` worked, the first name has already been erased from `employeeName`.

Comment: Well, I must admit I can think of situations where a string subtraction could be a helpful operator.  `"cat" - "dog"´ indeed is bull, but on occasion it might be helpful.  As this would be a very insecure operation, I'd suggest to only use it after testing if this can be done at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `std::string::substr`. Subtracting strings like that is invalid.

```
firstName = employeeName.substr(0, employeeName.find(" "));
```

The first parameter is the starting index of the substring you want to extract and the second parameter is the length of the substring.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "minus" (-) operator for [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). You have to use [std::string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) or [std::string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)

If you really want to use - operator, you can overload it.

Answer (score 2):

How would you define a minus operator for a string? Would you subtract from the beginning? Or the end?

Moreover, what is `"cat" - "dog"`? This operator wouldn't make sense.

Instead, you might want to use string indices, i.e. `employeeName[i]`, and copy characters individually, or use `std::string::substr` or `std::string::erase`, as others have suggested.

I would find `substr()` the easiest, due to its ability to remove sections of string (in this case, the first and last name).