# how to compare the string and store the difference in a variable. c++

Tags: string, compare

```
str1="D:\\User\\Desktop\\result.jpg";
str2="D:\\User\\Desktop\\";
```

I want to get the difference between str1 and str2, which is "result.jpg" so that i could use the string "result.jpg" for something else.
Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Can't subtract two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412698/c-cant-subtract-two-strings)

Answer (score 0):

I would use string replace and find:

```
std::string string = std::regex_replace(string1, std::regex("\\" + str2), "");
```

It is only pseudocode.